# Python: How to implement a implicit equation containing 2D arrays with scipy sparce matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

Im trying to implement the following implicit equation in python, to solve for u(n+1):

[image]

I am simplifying by combining (delta t / delta x^2) into a constant alpha, and using the terms "u" for u(n+1) and "u0" for u(n).

u[i, j] - u0[i, j] = alpha*(u[i+1, j] + u[i-1, j] + u[i, j+1] + u[i, j-1] - 4*u[i, j]) + h[i, j]

Then the equation is adapted to the form Ax = b.

-alpha*u[i+1, j] + (1+4*alpha)u[i, j] - alpha * u[i-1, j] - alpha * u[i, j+1] - alpha*u[i, j-1] = u0[i,j] - h[i,j]

At this point im stuck, as ive only learnt/solved 1D implicit matrices before, where there is only u[i-1], u[i] and u[i+1] which fills the three diagonals for calculcation using scipys spdiags function.

How do i do this with two dimensions instead?

EDIT: for anyone wondering this in the future, i ended up reshaping the array into u[i*j] instead and working with that.

Comment: It may help to step back from the sparse matrix format, and work with dense numpy arrays - at least for a small test case.  You might, for example, have to use a 3d array.